# How to run a Unix terminal program and pre-input a few lines before handing it over to the user?

Tags: bash, unix

So I can do this:

```
program
```

And I can do this:

```
echo "foo" | program
```

But if I wanted to enter `foo` and then hand over input to the user, how do I do that?

First thing I tried was:

```
cat <(echo "foo") /dev/fd/0 | program
```

which sort of works, but then `program` sees its stdin is in non-terminal mode (even though there's terminal connected, indirectly), so that doesn't work properly.

Is there any standard Unix solution for this? Or some bash/ruby/whatever script that sets this up?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expect) (for [Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl)) or similar tools (e.g. [pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pexpect) for Python) for this.

Here's a simple example using my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) :

```
$ cat python.sh
export SEXPECT_SOCKFILE=/tmp/python-$$.sock

sexpect spawn python3
sexpect expect ">>> "

sexpect send -cr "print('hello world')"
sexpect expect ">>> "

sexpect send -cr "print('Entering interactive mode ...')"
sexpect expect ">>> "

sexpect interact
```

Run it:

```
$ bash python.sh
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 26 2021, 23:22:38) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hello world')
hello world
>>> print('Entering interactive mode ...')
Entering interactive mode ...
>>> exit                                 <-- manual input
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> exit()                               <-- manual input
$
```

Comment: Playing withOUT `expect` in [tag:bash], see: [Expect like bash functions using `script`](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/expectScr.sh.txt)

Answer (score 0):

### You syntax was near correct

Try this:

```
cat <(echo foo) - | program
```

or

```
( echo "foo" ; cat ) | program
```

### Sample:

First creating a little *`program`* working as a filter:

```
program() {
    sed -ue 's/^/Altered: /'
}
```

Then

```
( printf '%s: %s\n' A foo b bar c baz;cat ) | program
Altered: A: foo
Altered: b: bar
Altered: c: baz
```

There, your console terminal should stay waiting for user input...

If you hit something like *`Hello world!`*<kbd>Return</kbd>, you will read on you console:

```
Altered: Hello world!
```

You may obtain same behaviour by using this syntax:

```
cat <(printf '%s: %s\n' A foo b bar c baz) - | program
```

but `<()` syntax is a *bashism*, so for portability, you may prefer

```
( echo foo ; cat ) | program
```